# Getting java to save a HTML file

Tags: java

I have code written in java that is grabbing the index page of a website, but when I try to save the file it saves a blank document.
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;

public class source {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String filename;

    filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the site");
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("files\\"+filename+".html");

    URL url = new URL("http://"+filename);


    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is =con.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line = null;


    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        outputFile.println(line);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
 Is there anything that I need to add to save html?

Comment: Also, why do you need to call `System.exit(0)` at the last line of `main`? Your program will exit anyway.

Comment: Also, a try catch finally { if (outputfile!=null) outputfile.close() ... } will be fine

Comment: Or use Java 7 and its try-with-resources syntax. Seriously, who targets Java 6 anymore?

Comment: follow-up on security.SE: [Prevent my site from being copied](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38460/prevent-my-site-from-being-copied)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, only two things are missing here.

You failed to close the reader and writer.

Add these at the end.

```
br.close();
outputFile.close();
```

PS: It would help us help you, if we know the input as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `System.exit()`. It's practically never needed and definitely not here. As paulsm4 said, you're missing the `outputFile.close()` (`br.close()` won't matter here), so the writes aren't flushed to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close / flush the data.

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line = null;


    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        outputFile.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
```

And your `System.exit()` causes Jvm to shutdown.